# Google Font Api not displaying on server but do locally

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am trying to use a Google Font, I have listed the font in the head of my html like this:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monsieur+La+Doulaise' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Then I have the font listed in the CSS code:

```
font-family: 'Monsieur La Doulaise', cursive;
```

When I preview the page from Dreamweaver it displays fine, but when I add the file to the server it does not.  Viewing in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to get it working on Fiddle...

See: [Your working code on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8pG8/)

What I did was end the link with a `/>` like below:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monsieur+La+Doulaise' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

A link is like a `div` and needs to be closed at the end

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Tried adding the '/' but has not made any difference.  I have even tried taking it back to basics, creating separate pages to literally just use the code you have but still does not work (it does work locally though just not on the server - I am hosting using dropbox.  If I increase the font size and upload to server I see the changes take affect but just not the font family.

Comment: @user2876766 do not use dropbox to host, invest in proper website hosting which is very cheap nowadays

Comment: I just wanted something free and easy to start with to build up the basics as I just wanted to create a basic website to play around with.  Would this be the reason the font is not working do you think?  If it is working locally on not from Dropbox that would make sense but I don't get why it should make a difference...

Comment: @user2876766 Dropbox is not for website hosting, it is for file storage... if it works locally and not on Dropbox then the issue would be with Dropbox. I's sure if you google free website hosting you may find somewhere